# Why is my MFC application hanging after interacting with both scroll-bars?

Tags: windows, debugging, mfc

I'm working on an MFC application (running under Win10) which includes a graphical CAD-style editor window. The editor window contains icons which the user can re-position and configure.

In layouts with many elements, we're finding that the editor window can hang for up to 30 seconds. This issue was *not* reported when most of our users were on Windows 7; it seems that this started to happen with Windows 10, but I haven't gone back to Win7 to confirm.

The exact sequence of actions triggering the hang is:

1. Scroll horizontally (using the horizontal scroll-bar)
2. Scroll vertically (using the vertical scroll-bar)
3. Application hangs for about 20-30 seconds, then recovers

Minor variations of the steps above also trigger a temporary hang; for example, scrolling vertically with the mouse button, and then scrolling horizontally with the scroll-bar, also triggers the hang.

The hang or lock-up always recovers. I have also noticed that other applications in Windows become temporarily 'frozen' (as in: I can't drag the window around, and UI updates become very slow, for *all* applications running when this hang occurs).

I'm unsure where to start debugging, because I have a feeling that this is happening at the OS level; my first guess would be to start profiling different lines of code to target the exact OS call causing the delay, but I'm not sure how well this approach will work if the element causing the hang is something other than a function-call in my code; for example, maybe some queue is nearly full in the OS, causing the message-pump to slow down without any particular OS call appearing to be slow.

My questions are:

1. Are there any changes in Windows 10 w.r.t. large CWnd counts, which may interact with scrolling to cause a hang?
2. What tools does Windows provide for debugging this scenario? Should I be looking at WinDbg? Should I focus on profiling the issue without using any special-purpose debug tools?

I'm going to work on this issue from the internal application perspective (to rule out the possibility that our code is directly causing the hang), but I would appreciate any guidance on the best approach for debugging this issue assuming that we don't have something obvious like a 30-second function call in our code.

---

Thank you for the comments. Here's some new information:

- CPU usage is low during this event; hovering around 1-3%, so my code is not being bottlenecked by CPU.
- I added TRACE statements to my HSCROLL and VSCROLL handlers at both the entry-point and exit-point. The hang appears to be happening *before* the entry to my VSCROLL handler, immediately after clicking the scroll bar with my left mouse-button.
- The code has a handler for LButtonDown, but it does not appear to be hit when the scroll-bar is clicked
- The application has 208 GDI objects and 66 User objects, so I think we are well below the limit
- This issue has been observed on all tested Win10 PCs, it is not unique to a single machine

Going to try Spy++ now.

I don't see any obvious issues with the handlers, and my debug output seems to rule out them as the culprit, but here they are for completeness:

```
void CDrawing60View::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar) 
{
    TRACE("OnHScroll:Begin\r\n");

    int i = 1;
    switch ( nSBCode )
    {
    case SB_LEFT :  //   Scroll to far left.
        i = 2 ;
        break ;
    case SB_ENDSCROLL : //   End scroll.
        i = 3 ;
        break ;

    case SB_LINELEFT :  //   Scroll left.  left arrow on left side of scroll bar
        i = 4 ;
        break ;

    case SB_LINERIGHT : //   Scroll right.  right arrow on right side of scroll bar
        i = 5 ;
        break ;

    case SB_PAGELEFT :  //   Scroll one page left.
        i = 6 ;
        break ;

    case SB_PAGERIGHT : //   Scroll one page right.
        i = 7 ;
        break ;

    case SB_RIGHT : //   Scroll to far right.
        i = 8 ;
        break ;

    case SB_THUMBPOSITION : //   Scroll to absolute position. The current position is specified by the nPos parameter.
        i = 9 ;
        break ;

    case SB_THUMBTRACK :    //   Drag scroll box to specified position. 
        i = 10;
        break ;
    }

    CFormView::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);

    CPoint p = GetScrollPosition(); // p = how much we have scrolled in the horizontal/vertical directions

    SNAP_TO_8_PIXELS (p.x);
    SNAP_TO_8_PIXELS  ( p.y)
    ScrollToPosition ( p ) ;

    MoveDrawing . LastScrollPositionX = p . x ; // used when saving the drawing
    MoveDrawing . LastScrollPositionY = p . y ;

    TRACE("OnHScroll:End\r\n");
}

void CDrawing60View::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar) 
{
    TRACE("OnVScroll:Begin\r\n");

    int i = 0;
    switch ( nSBCode )
    {
    case SB_BOTTOM :    //   Scroll to bottom.
        i = 2 ;
        break ;
    case SB_ENDSCROLL : //   End scroll.
        break ;
    case SB_LINEDOWN :  //   Scroll one line down.
        i = 2 ;
        break ;
    case SB_LINEUP :    //   Scroll one line up.
        i = 2 ;
        break ;
    case SB_PAGEDOWN :  //   Scroll one page down.
        i = 2 ;
        break ;
    case SB_PAGEUP :    //   Scroll one page up.
        i = 2 ;
        break ;
    case SB_THUMBPOSITION : //   Scroll to the absolute position. The current position is provided in nPos.
        i = 2 ;
        break ;
    case SB_THUMBTRACK :    //   Drag scroll box to specified position. The current position is provided in nPos.
        i = 2 ;
        break ;
    case SB_TOP :   //   Scroll to top. 
        i = 2 ;
        break ;
    }

    CFormView::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
    CPoint p = GetScrollPosition(); // p = how much we have scrolled in the horizontal/vertical directions

    SNAP_TO_8_PIXELS (p.x);
    SNAP_TO_8_PIXELS ( p.y)
    ScrollToPosition ( p ) ;

    MoveDrawing . LastScrollPositionX = p . x ; // used when saving the drawing
    MoveDrawing . LastScrollPositionY = p . y ;

    TRACE("OnVScroll:End\r\n");
}
```

---

Ok, Spy++ has yielded some interesting results. When I run Spy++, I am *unable to reproduce this issue!*. I wonder if this suggests a race condition in my handlers, because the only effect that I can imagine Spy++ having is to slow things down.

Comment: *>>I have also noticed that other applications in Windows become temporarily 'frozen' (as in: I can't drag the window around, and UI updates become very slow, for all applications running when this hang occurs).* 
It might mean that your app eats a lot of CPU time, take a look at CPU usage in task manager. If so, then investigate what function in your code causes that.

Comment: Maybe consider posting (some of) your code that handles the scroll requests: there might be an inadvertent data-race happening between the `HScroll` and `VScroll` handlers.

Comment: I haven't seen this freezing issue in Windows 10. There might be something wrong with your Windows setup, or you are running resource intensive apps. Use the task manager to check how many GDI handles is used by your applications, or if other applications are using up resources.

Comment: Some of the Windows background tasks (Defender, Cortana, User Experience etc etc) can indeed cause UI delays and make the system look like frozen. Maybe check if any of these intervenes and causes you troubles. As for the application, the comment by @AdrianMole above is probably the answer. Use tracing (not debugging) to check whether some parts of your code are getting called again and again. What happens in the H/VScroll event handlers? Doing something CPU- or graphics-intensive operation in there? Also check the code that calculates or sets the scrollable area's size.

Comment: There are no changes in the limits to window counts. The limit is the same: 10,000 USER objects of which a window is a USER object from the USER heap. You can use task manager in detailed view to view USER object counts. You have to add the column in the detailed view because it does not show USER object counts by default.

Comment: It sounds like your app gets stuck into a SendMessage()/handler loop.  You can use MSVC's Spy++ utility to check for messages handled by your app,  Your bug is probably in the handlers for scrolling messages.  Posting the code for your handler would help.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy interesting - see my new comments, Spy++ prevents the issue from appearing.

Comment: Interesting indeed. You will have to use traces, then.

Comment: Oh.  Do not call the base class' OnHScroll() or OnVScroll(), You must handle the scroll, scroll direction and step/page size within the switch block.  Do not call GetScrollPosition(), use the nPos parameter instead. Then call RedrawWindow() to refresh your graphics.

Comment: Scroll messages are a pain.

Comment: Hi Roy, I've applied your suggestions. No change. I'm starting to think scrolling isn't the true root-cause. I have narrowed it down to something that happens when my application has focus, then loses focus, then re-gains focus. 

Also, I was able to reproduce this issue using a minimal SDI app that just creates a ton of controls in a dialog view, so it's probably related to the quantity of control elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a Windows OS issue. Microsoft Support provided a high-level explanation: newer Windows features are interfering with my application.

It seems that my investigation was pointing in the correct direction: `ntdll.dll` or `dwm.exe` being the culprit, not my executable.

The fact that Spy++ smooths out my issue is pretty telling. This indicates that we are *not* running up against a strict performance limitation, and it also shows that it's not my application stalling; something at the OS level is interfering with itself.

The Microsoft Support rep directed me to use the Compatibility Administrator tool included in the Windows ADK under Application Compatibility Tools. Using this wizard, I generated a shim database (.sdb) containing a fix for **ScrollWindowsExFlags**.

Then, I used the following command in an elevated command-line to install the shim database:

```
sdbinst -u <path to the sdb file>
```

From Microsoft Support:

> Having many child windows to scroll is the cause.  When they are
>   scrolled, DWM has to update the internal data for each window that is
>   moved.  Having too many of them overwhelms DWM.