# How do I force a redraw of WIN32 scrolled window while holding scrollbar down

Tags: windows, winapi, scrollbar

[image]We've noticed an issue with ScrollWindowEx on our Windows app. Because there are a lot of child windows, if you hold down the scrollbar and move around, it causes a huge stall in DesktopWindowManager.

This is documented here

[Why is my MFC application hanging after interacting with both scroll-bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59655147/why-is-my-mfc-application-hanging-after-interacting-with-both-scroll-bars)

So, I've taken the call to ScrollWindowEx out and now I can move my scrollbar with no issues, however the window and all its children only get drawn at the new position when I let go of the scrollbar.

It seems that my entire program stalls and gets stuck in the message loop when the scroll bar is held down. This isnt a problem if we can force the window that the scrollbar is attached to to update. But how do I do that ?

I've tried this

```
UpdateWindow(pPane);
RedrawWindow(pPane,NULL,NULL,RDW_ALLCHILDREN|RDW_INVALIDATE|RDW_ERASE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT | RDW_UPDATENOW);
```

And it does update and redraw - you can see the glitching - BUT it redraws it at the position that it was last left at. Not where the new position of the scroll bar would set it.

Im calling

```
SetScrollInfo(...)
```

with the correct parameters, otherwise it wouldn't work normally

How can I get it to redraw the window and its children with the correct parameters, whilst the scroll bar is held down?

This is my scroll message handler

```
case WM_VSCROLL:
    {
        int iVScrollPos;
        SCROLLINFO vsi;
        ZeroMemory(&vsi, sizeof(SCROLLINFO));

        vsi.cbSize=sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
        vsi.fMask=SIF_ALL;
        GetScrollInfo(hWnd,SB_VERT,&vsi);
        iVScrollPos=vsi.nPos;

        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
           case SB_LINEUP:
                if(vsi.nPos>vsi.nMin)
                   vsi.nPos=vsi.nPos-10;
                break;
           case SB_PAGEUP:
                vsi.nPos = vsi.nPos - vsi.nPage;
                break;
           case SB_LINEDOWN:
                if(vsi.nPos<vsi.nMax)
                   vsi.nPos=vsi.nPos+10;
                break;
           case SB_PAGEDOWN:
                vsi.nPos = vsi.nPos + vsi.nPage;
                break;
           case SB_THUMBTRACK:
                vsi.nPos=vsi.nTrackPos;
                break;
        }

        vsi.nMin=0;
        vsi.nMax=pOW->dialogysize;          
        vsi.nPage=sy;           

        SetScrollInfo(hWnd,SB_VERT,&vsi,TRUE);
        GetScrollInfo(hWnd, SB_VERT, &vsi);     
        
        if(vsi.nPos != iVScrollPos)
        {                 
RedrawWindow(hWnd,NULL,NULL,RDW_ALLCHILDREN|RDW_INVALIDATE|RDW_ERASE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT | RDW_UPDATENOW);
}
```

The window redraws as you move the scroll bar, but in the same place it was when you held the mouse down on the scrollbar. It onlyupdates position when you let go of the mouse button.

Thanks

Shaun

EDIT - Ive created a sample that reproduces the behaviour.  Note we have a separate window class to hold the multiple edit windows. I havent handled the WM_SIZE and WM_MOVE messages in this demo but the code should work with the window as it is.

IF USESCROLL is defined in and you move the scrollbar up and down it casues a lockup in DesktopWindowManager

IF USESCROLL is not commented in, then the trackPos in the structure still gets updated and I call reDrawWindow, but the child edit windows dont move as I scroll the scrollbar.

As I dont want to have the lockup, how can I get them to move please ?

Thanks again

Shaun

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LRESULT CALLBACK PaneProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    
    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = "Class";

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = PaneProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = "Pane";

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        (LPCSTR)"Class",                     // Window class
        (LPCSTR)"Test",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW| WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_SYSMENU,            // Window style
        200,200,400,400,
        NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
    
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
      HWND hwndPane = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        (LPCSTR)"Pane",                     // Window class
        (LPCSTR)"Test",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL,            // Window style
        220,220,400,400,
        hwnd,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
      
    if (hwndPane == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
    {
        HWND eb = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), NULL,ES_AUTOHSCROLL  | WS_CHILD| WS_VISIBLE, 16, 16+24*i, 64, 24, hwndPane, (HMENU)i+10000, hInstance, NULL);
        char tmp[64];
        sprintf(tmp,"%d",i);
        SetWindowText(eb,tmp);
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    ShowWindow(hwndPane, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.
    while(1)
    {
        MSG msg = { };
        
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0,0,PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    
        Sleep(10);
    }

    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK PaneProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {

    case WM_CREATE:

        int iVScrollPos;
        SCROLLINFO vsi;
        ZeroMemory(&vsi, sizeof(SCROLLINFO));

        vsi.cbSize=sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
        vsi.fMask=SIF_ALL;      
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd,SB_VERT,&vsi);
        iVScrollPos=vsi.nPos;

        vsi.nMin=0;
        vsi.nMax=16+24*200+40;      
        vsi.nPage=400;          

        SetScrollInfo(hwnd,SB_VERT,&vsi,TRUE);
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &vsi);     
        break;
            
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_VSCROLL:
    {
           int iVScrollPos;
           SCROLLINFO vsi;
           ZeroMemory(&vsi, sizeof(SCROLLINFO));

           vsi.cbSize=sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
           vsi.fMask=SIF_ALL;       
           GetScrollInfo(hwnd,SB_VERT,&vsi);
           iVScrollPos=vsi.nPos;

            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
               case SB_THUMBTRACK:
                    vsi.nPos=vsi.nTrackPos;
                    break;
            }

            vsi.nMin=0;
            vsi.nMax=16+24*200+40;      
            vsi.nPage=400;          

            SetScrollInfo(hwnd,SB_VERT,&vsi,TRUE);
            GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &vsi);     
            
            if(vsi.nPos != iVScrollPos)
            {
                float ScrollAmtY=-(vsi.nPos - iVScrollPos);

#define USESCROLL
#ifdef USESCROLL
                int ok=ScrollWindowEx(hwnd ,0,ScrollAmtY,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SW_INVALIDATE|SW_ERASE|SW_SCROLLCHILDREN);
#else
                UpdateWindow(hwnd);
                RedrawWindow(hwnd,NULL,NULL,RDW_ALLCHILDREN|RDW_INVALIDATE|RDW_ERASE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT | RDW_UPDATENOW);
#endif
            }
            return 0;
        }
        break;


    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: While the scrollbar is being dragged, it's `nTrackPos` that gets updated, not `nPos`. In your `WM_VSCROLL` handler you need to "copy" the tracking position to the real position with `SetScrollInfo`.

Comment: Is your project win32 or MFC? Can you provide a minimal reproducible code sample? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096158/11128312) what you want?

Comment: I do have SetScrollInfo in the message handler.  And yes, my code is very like the example provided, but if I call ScrollWindowEx, then because I have a lot of child windows on the scrollable window, DesktopWindow Manager gets overwhelmed and the computer locks up for seconds at a time. Cant even CTRL ALT DEL.
   }

Comment: Yes, its Win32.

Comment: As [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60063806/11128312) pointed out,  this seems to happen on win10 machines, and Microsoft support has given a corresponding solution, using the [Compatibility Administrator tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/compatibility-administrator-users-guide). Have you tried?

Comment: `The window redraws as yo... you held the mouse down on the scrollbar. ` The code you provided is not enough to reproduce this problem. But what is certain is that `RedrawWindow` is only used for redrawing, it will call `WM_PAINT` message, not sure whether your child window has its own message loop. If there are too many `WM_PAINT` in the message queue and the `WM_PAINT` message is not processed in time, it will indeed easily cause message blockage. If you can provide  [a Minimal, Reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I would appreciate it very much

Comment: I'll try to sort out the minimum repro sample code. I haven't tried the fix yet as it would involve extra setup for people who use the app. I was hoping to fix it without this.

Comment: Thanks sharing the sample. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your behaviour. If USESCROLL is defined, my TASK Manger(is it same with DesktopWindowManager?) not lockup. If USESCROLL is not commented in, the child edit windows will move as I scroll the scrollbar. Like the [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6gSF.gif) shows. Can you share a video or gif to describe the problem?(Don't forget to erase personal privacy)

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for trying this.  I've added a picture showing that DesktopWindowManager is taking a lot of time. What you need to do is scroll up and down whilst holding the scrollbar. It locks up when you let go and try to click on any other explorer window.  What I want to be able to do is update the window myself whilst the scroll bar is held down, but if I comment out #define USESCROLL, so it calls UpdateWindow and RedrawWindow, it doesnt update the child windows to the position of the scroll.

Comment: UPDATE: If I use ScrollWindowEx I still get the lockup, However, after looking at the behaviour of the sample I wrote, compared with the game, I found the issue.  I was expecting that moving the scroll bar on the parent window would automatically move the positions of the child windows. IT does not - my code ( which was mainly written about 10 years ago ) moves them itself when the scroll bar is released and the code gets out of the msg loop.  If I set the positions of all of the child windows to reflect the scrollbar and then call RedrawWindow then they move while the scrollbar is still held.